# Twitter4j counting the number of tweets found

Tags: java, processing, twitter4j

Here's my method for finding a hashtag:

```
void getNewTweets()
{
  //try the search
  try
  {
    Query query = new Query(searchString);
    //get the last 50 tweets
    query.count(2);
    QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
    tweets = result.getTweets();

    System.out.println(tweets); 
  }  
  //if there is an error then catch it and print it out
  catch (TwitterException te)
  {
    System.out.println("Failed to search tweets: " + te.getMessage());
    System.exit(-1);
  }
}
```

I'm using the Twitter4j library. How would I count the number of tweets found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the tweets in an ArrayList and fetch the size of the ArrayList to display the number of tweets.

```
ArrayList tweets = (ArrayList) result.getTweets();
System.out.println(tweets.size());
```

Comment: I was about to comment on this thread saying I figured it out using a similar int listSize = tweets.size();

Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [`QueryResult.getCount()`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/QueryResult.html#getCount--) function.

```
Query query = new Query(searchString);
QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);

int count = results.getCount();
System.out.println("tweet count: " + count);
```